# How to add result of two sum case statements?

Tags: mysql

I am preparing a report where i need to add the result of two case statements and show it in new column.

i tried doing this : SUM('4MPBS') +SUM('8MBPS')  AS total
but not giving correct figures.

```sql
SELECT DATE(bc.cycle_start_date) AS cycle,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 2MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 2MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 4MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 4MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 8MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 8MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 16MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 16MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 25MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 25MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 50MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 50MBPS,
SUM( CASE WHEN bib.`category`='Discount Monthly Charges' THEN (bib.`itemDisplayValue`*-1) ELSE 0 END) AS discount,
 SUM('4MPBS') +SUM('8MBPS')  AS total
FROM `broadband_invoicebreakdown` bib,`broadband_invoicedetails` bid,`broadbandcycle` bc
WHERE bib.`invoiceId`=bid.invoiceid AND bid.cycleid=bc.cycle_id AND bc.cycle_type !='U'
GROUP BY bc.cycle_type
```

The result i am getting is below .The total of 3rd and 4th column is coming wrong.

cycle       2MBPS   4MBPS     8MBPS     16MBPS    25MBPS   50MBPS   discount   total

---

2019-04-01  0.00    116.88    260.00    272.00    940.64   0.00     0.00          **2472**
2019-03-15  0.00    95295.20  34740.00  22644.00  8268.96  4050.00  0.00         **44544**
2019-03-22  0.00    41745.00  15710.00  8704.00   2668.76  3712.50  0.00         **21996**

It should come like:

cycle       2MBPS   4MBPS     8MBPS     16MBPS    25MBPS   50MBPS   discount   total

---

2019-04-01  0.00    116.88    260.00    272.00    940.64   0.00     0.00          **376.88**
2019-03-15  0.00    95295.20  34740.00  22644.00  8268.96  4050.00  0.00         **13003.00**
2019-03-22  0.00    41745.00  15710.00  8704.00   2668.76  3712.50  0.00
**57455.00**

Comment: SUM('4MPBS') +SUM('8MBPS')  - you need to replace this with SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 4MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END)  +
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 8MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS total

Comment: yes it worked..thanks :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this;

```sql
SELECT DATE(bc.cycle_start_date) AS cycle,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 2MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 2MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 4MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 4MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 8MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 8MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 16MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 16MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 25MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 25MBPS,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.`broadbandPlan`='Smart Broadband - 50MB' THEN bib.`itemDisplayValue` ELSE 0 END) AS 50MBPS,
SUM( CASE WHEN bib.`category`='Discount Monthly Charges' THEN (bib.`itemDisplayValue`*-1) ELSE 0 END) AS discount,
SUM(CASE WHEN bib.broadbandPlan='Smart Broadband - 4MB' THEN bib.itemDisplayValue ELSE 0 END) + SUM(CASE WHEN bib.broadbandPlan='Smart Broadband - 8MB' THEN bib.itemDisplayValue ELSE 0 END) AS total  
FROM `broadband_invoicebreakdown` bib,`broadband_invoicedetails` bid,`broadbandcycle` bc
WHERE bib.`invoiceId`=bid.invoiceid AND bid.cycleid=bc.cycle_id AND bc.cycle_type !='U'
GROUP BY bc.cycle_type
```

Comment: No worries. Please accept the answer as correct when you can :) @BaljotSingh